# How is this read?

Tags: word-choice

Do you have any idea how 1910s is read? I know, for example, 1920s is read "nineteen twenties". This is also the case with "the thirties, the forties, the fifties, etc". But is there "the tennies" in English?

Comment: As an alternative, you can also say "The early 19th century"

Comment: @Invoker - It's rather late to correct this but the 1910s is not the early 19th century, it is the early 20th century

Answer (score 3):

1910s would be pronounced as Nineteen-tens, [this BBC article on the 2010s](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/worldtonight/2009/12/happy_twentyten.html) states "twenty-tens".

While the decade itself is either the "tens" or the "teens".

However, there's even [a bit of confusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010s#Mixed_pronunciation) to how an individual year is pronounced in the 2010s!

Comment: Confusion, or inconsistency? I use both conventions indiscriminately.